# Validating the data entered in numeric input in RShiny

Tags: r, validation, shiny

I am developing the Shiny app in which if the user enters non-numeric characters, the value should be changed to the value mentioned in updateNumericInput().

Here is my **Rcode**

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage (
  numericInput("current", "Current Week",value = 40, min = 40, max = 80)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$current, { 
    updateNumericInput(session,"current", value = ({ if(!(is.numeric(input$current))){40}
                           if(!(is.null(input$current) || is.na(input$current))){
                           if(input$current < 40){
                             40 
                           }else if(input$current > 80){
                             80
                           } else{
                             return (isolate(input$current))
                           } 
                         } 
      })
    )
  })

  }

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

Can anyone help me with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage (
  numericInput("current", "Current Week",value = 40, min = 40, max = 80)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$current, { 
    updateNumericInput(session,"current", value = ({ if(!(is.numeric(input$current))){40}
      else if(!(is.null(input$current) || is.na(input$current))){
        if(input$current < 40){
          40 
        }else if(input$current > 80){
          80
        } else{
          return (isolate(input$current))
        } 
      } 
      else{40}
    })
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Similar to this. If I enter **!(is.numeric(input$current))** in **if else** in my existing code it is not working.. Any solution available for this? @Pork Chop

Comment: it has to be evaluate first

Comment: use my solution

Comment: With your solution, I cannot check if there is no value entered in numericInput. Can you elaborate please!!

Comment: I have updated my code as per your solution. But still I didn't get the expected output. The updated code is above. Can you help me out? @Pork Chop

Comment: It works.. Thanks.. I accept your solution. @Pork Chop

Comment: @NevedhaAyyanar please click accept the answer if this is what you are looking for.  Avoid saying `thanks` and `it works` as other member of the community will need to reference it too https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers